# Share multiple link with Facebook SDK 4

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was wandering if it is possible to share multiple links on facebook all in once.
My goal is to let the user share multiple videos.
I can't use the ShareVideoContent class because these videos are remote, so i have to share the links.
That's why i'm using the ShareLinkContent class of the Facebook SDK (4.5.0).
It works fine, but i can upload only one video (one link) at a time.

So i wanted to ask if there is a way to share more links on Facebook, but clicking only once on the share button.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Facebook only supports a single link preview for posts. That means you can only post a link to a single video at a time, if you want the video to be playable from the resulting story. (This requires that the webpage containing the video - which is what you link to - is properly annotated with OpenGraph `<meta>` tags.

If you don't use any share dialogs, but use the [`/me/feed` Graph API endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed) to post directly, you can post a story with multiple links in the description, but that will look less well integrated. Also note that you are not allowed to prefill any content that the user is supposed to share.

Comment: ok, this is what i was thinking... so there's no way to share multiple links in a row

Comment: I expanded my answer to also cover the use of the Graph API.